# issue with *.ics splitting strings with more than one line *Python*

Tags: python, icalendar

I have tried as many methods I could find, and always got the same result, but there must be a fix for this?

I am downloading an ICS from a website, were one of the lines "Summary", is split in two.
When I load this into a string these two lines get automaticly joined into 1 string, unless there are "\n".

so I have tried to replace both "\n" and "\r", but there is no change on my issue.

**Code**

```
from icalendar import Calendar, Event
from datetime import datetime
import icalendar
import urllib.request
import re
from clear import clear_screen

cal = Calendar()

def download_ics():
    url = "https://www.pogdesign.co.uk/cat/download_ics/7d903a054695a48977d46683f29384de"
    file_name = "pogdesign.ics"
    urllib.request.urlretrieve(url, file_name)

def get_start_time(time):
    time = datetime.strftime(time, "%A - %H:%M")
    return time

def get_time(time):
    time = datetime.strftime(time, "%H:%M")
    return time

def check_Summary(text):
    #newline = re.sub('[\r\n]', '', text)
    newline = text.translate(str.maketrans("", "", "\r\n"))
    return newline

def main():
    download_ics()
    clear_screen()
    e = open('pogdesign.ics', 'rb')
    ecal = icalendar.Calendar.from_ical(e.read())
    for component in ecal.walk():
        if component.name == "VEVENT":
            summary = check_Summary(component.get("SUMMARY"))
            print(summary)
            print("\t Start : " + get_start_time(component.decoded("DTSTART")) + " - " + get_time(component.decoded("DTEND")))

            print()
    e.close()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

**output**

> Young Sheldon S06E11 - Ruthless, Toothless, and a Week ofBed Rest
> Start : Friday - 02:00 - 02:30
>
> The Good Doctor S06E11 - The Good Boy
> Start : Tuesday - 04:00 - 05:00
>
> National Treasure: Edge of History S01E08 - Family Tree
> Start : Thursday - 05:59 - 06:59
>
> National Treasure: Edge of History S01E09 - A Meeting withSalazar
> Start : Thursday - 05:59 - 06:59
>
> The Last of Us S01E03 - Long Long Time
> Start : Monday - 03:00 - 04:00
>
> The Last of Us S01E04 - Please Hold My Hand
> Start : Monday - 03:00 - 04:00
>
> Anne Rice's Mayfair Witches S01E04 - Curiouser and Curiouser
> Start : Monday - 03:00 - 04:00
>
> Anne Rice's Mayfair Witches S01E05 - The Thrall
> Start : Monday - 03:00 - 04:00
>
> The Ark S01E01 - Everyone Wanted to Be on This Ship
> Start : Thursday - 04:00 - 05:00

I have looked through all kinds of solutions, like converting the text to "utf-8" and "ISO-8859-8".
I have tried some functions I found in the icalendar.
have even asked ChatGPT for help.

as you might see on the first line on the output:
Young Sheldon S06E11 - Ruthless, Toothless, and a Week **ofBed Rest**
and
National Treasure: Edge of History S01E09 - A Meeting **withSalazar**

These two lines in the downloaded ics, is on two seperate lines, and i cannot manage to make them split, or not join at all...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So far as the `icalendar.Calendar` class is concerned, that ical is incorrectly formatted.

`icalendar.Calendar.from_ical()` calls `icalendar.Calendar.parser.Contentlines.from_ical()` [which is](https://github.com/collective/icalendar/blob/v5.0.4/src/icalendar/parser.py#L354-L360)

```
    def from_ical(cls, ical, strict=False):
        """Unfold the content lines in an iCalendar into long content lines.
        """
        ical = to_unicode(ical)
        # a fold is carriage return followed by either a space or a tab
        return cls(uFOLD.sub('', ical), strict=strict)
```

where `uFOLD` is `re.compile('(\r?\n)+[ \t]')`

That means it's removing each series of newlines that is followed by one space or tab character – not replacing it with a space. The ical file you're retrieving has e.g.

```
SUMMARY:Young Sheldon S06E11 - \\nRuthless\\, Toothless\\, and a Week of\r\n Bed Rest\r\n
```

so when `of\r\n Bed` is matched it becomes `ofBed`.

This line-folding format [is defined in RFC 2445](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2445#section-4.1) which gives the example

> For example the line:
>
> ```
> DESCRIPTION:This is a long description that exists on a long line.
> ```
>
> Can be represented as:
>
> ```
> DESCRIPTION:This is a lo
>  ng description
>   that exists on a long line.
> ```

which makes clear that the implementation in `from_ical()` is correct.

If you're quite sure that the source ical will always fold lines on words, you could adjust for that by adding a space after each line fold, like:

```
    ecal = icalendar.Calendar.from_ical(e.read().replace(b'\r\n ', b'\r\n  '))
```